# which is better? using cd and execute or using absolute path?

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose I would like to do some operation like `touch/rm`etc  on a specific directory in shell script.
Firstly, I can do `cd` to that directory and do it. 
Secondly, I can use absolute path to do that.

My question is which one will be better in performance perspective? Which one is faster?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can time it yourself:

```
function timeThis {
    n=0 
    path="test/a"
    rm $path
    if [[ "$1" == abs ]]; then
        path="$(pwd)/$path"
    fi  
    echo "$path"
    while [[ $n -lt 10000 ]]; do
        touch $path
        let n++ 
    done
}

echo "absolute"
time timeThis abs 
echo "relative"
time timeThis rel
```

with this I get:

```
absolute

real    0m5.502s
user    0m3.394s
sys 0m2.398s

relative    
real    0m5.492s
user    0m3.599s
sys 0m2.373s
```

so it is almost the same for this many iterations on the path I tried

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what directory you want to access,ie. if the path is too long,the fastest would be absolute path method,whereas it would make no sense to use the path for something in the immediate next directory.

Comment: I said it would be in shell script. have you considered that? @Sai Swaroop